# C++ thread procedure from class

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

Im writing some program using C++ and OpenCV.

What I want to achieve is to make 2 threads and pass them 2 functions from my class to speed up calculations.

Im not good at explaining, so I will just show You where is the problem!

Here is my class:

```
class mainApp
{  
private:
cv::Mat frame;
int frameNumber;

HANDLE pbasThread;
HANDLE skinsegThread;
std::vector < HANDLE > threads;

PBAS pbas; 
cv::Mat pbasResult; 

SKINSEG skinseg;
cv::Mat skinsegResult;

private:
void find_connected_components(cv::Mat *mask, int poly1_hull0 = 1, float perimScale  = 4.0, int* num = NULL, CvRect* bbs = NULL, CvPoint* centers = NULL); 

static void __cdecl pbasThreadProc( void * Args )
{
    cv::Mat bluredImage;
    cv::GaussianBlur(frame, bluredImage, cv::Size(5,5), 1.5);
    pbas.process(&bluredImage, &pbasResult);
    cv::medianBlur(pbasResult, pbasResult, 5);
    _endthread();
};
}
```

Something like that. Then I would like to do this in my mainApp:main function:

```
while(1)
{
HANDLE pbasThread =( HANDLE ) _beginthread( pbasThreadProc, 0, (void *)this );

        threads.push_back(pbasThread);

        if( threads.size() > 0 )
        WaitForMultipleObjects( threads.size(), & threads[ 0 ], TRUE, INFINITE );
...

}
```

In this example I use only 1 thread, but normally I would use more. The problem is that thread procedure has to be static in order to compile the code, but when the procedure is static, i can't use non static objects and functions inside of it.. which leads me to the big problem.

Any idea's how to solve this? (i can't make everything static.. it has to be as it is).

Comment: Can you not put all your pbas, cv etc. into one class and pass an instance of it as the 'void * Args'?  Either make a global-scope array of the things, or new them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add non-static method `ExecuteInThread` to your class `mainApp`:

```
void mainApp::ExecuteInThread()
{
    cv::Mat bluredImage;
    cv::GaussianBlur(frame, bluredImage, cv::Size(5,5), 1.5);
    pbas.process(&bluredImage, &pbasResult);
    cv::medianBlur(pbasResult, pbasResult, 5);
}
```

and call it in your thread function:

```
static void __cdecl pbasThreadProc( void * Args )
{
    mainApp* app = static_cast<mainApp*>(Args);

    app->ExecuteInThread();
    _endthread();
};
```

You should also pass a pointer to the object of `mainApp` class to `pbasThreadProc` function, but you already did it in the string

```
HANDLE pbasThread =( HANDLE ) _beginthread( pbasThreadProc, 0, (void *)this );
```

as I understood.

Comment: 'pbasResult' is immutable?

Comment: @Martin James You are right. There is nothing about thread safety in my answer. But it is a next step and only author of the question could really know about the need of using some synchronization code there.